# On jenkins, how can I trigger test after merge pull request

Tags: github, jenkins

Using trigger push + github plugin will trigger test after each push(including merge pull request), however, this method require to select github repo by Source Code Management, which will automatically download code every time.

So, is there a way that I can trigger jenkins each time a pull request has been merged into master branch without automatically downloading code?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you want to download the code? Isn't that what continuous integration is about?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to react to changes in your code, why don't you need to download the changes ?